# Which of the following is not true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group with 81 elements and $H$ a subgroup with 27 elements. Which of the following is not true?
>
> - **(a)** $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$
> - **(b)** $Z(H)\neq 1$
> - **(c)** $H'=1$
> - **(d)** $G'\subseteq H$

I know that (b) is true. Since the center of every nontrivial p-group is nontrivial (p is prime). Also, (d) is true since $G/H$ has 3 elements and hence $G/H$ is abelian. So $G'\subseteq H$. But (a) and (c)?

Comment: if a is correct so d is correct as well.

Comment: How can you say for (d) that $G/H$ is an abelian group if you don't know whether (a) is true?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen For subgroup $H$ of $G$, $G'\subseteq H$ if and only if $G/H$ be abelian

Comment: The point of @HagenvonEitzen was that you need to know $H$ is normal to be able to talk about the quotient group $G/H$. Or, to rephrase your statement, for $H$ a subgroup of $G$, one has $G' \subseteq H$ if and only if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $G/H$ is abelian,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(a) is also true, for instance because a subgroup of a finite group whose index is the smallest prime dividing the order of the group is normal.

You may also want to see why (c) fails. You need to know an example of a nonabelian group of order 27, and then take the direct product with a group of order 3.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Sorry Prof., May I ask you to have a look at my approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to show that every non-abelian $p-$ group $G$ of order $p^3$ has this property: $$Z(G)\cong G'\cong\mathbb Z/p\Bbb{Z}$$

Comment: Please explain for me by details.

Comment: @aliakbar: When $|G|=p^3$ and $G$ is non-abelian so $|G/Z(G)|=p, p^2, 1$. If $|G/Z(G)|=p$ then $G/Z(G)$ would be cyclic and therefore $G$ be abelian. If $|G/Z(G)|=1$ then $G\cong Z(G)$ and again $G$ be abelian.So $|G/Z(G)|=p^2$ and therefore $|Z(G)|=p$ and $G'\subset Z(G)$. So the option c would be your option.